# Python script takes input of four elements and outputs a valid 4 × 4 Sudoku grid in O(n) time, but only when given non-repeating elements

Tags: python, sudoku

### Introduction

I've found a clever and fun thing to do after solving a n<sup>2</sup> × n<sup>2</sup> sudoku puzzle. I can take 
a grid as such as this one and hard-code its indices as constraints to output other 4 × 4 latin squares in poly-time

[image]

Now, I took each successive row and hardcoded as indices with successive print statements.

Indices constraints

```
0123
3210
1032
2301
```

Working Code

```
print('enter with [1,2,3...] brackets')
text = input()[1:-1].split(',')
print(text[0], text[1], text[2], text[3])
print(text[3], text[2], text[1], text[0])
print(text[1], text[0], text[3], text[2])
print(text[2], text[3], text[0], text[1])
```

### Question

Being a novice at python I'm asking is there a better way of hardcoding the Sudoku's pattern with fewer lines of code?

*Because it would be daunting to have to write larger constraints for larger latin squares.*

I would appreciate it to keep it O(n) time because I have a desire to input integers besides just elements 1-4. But, 100-104 and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `json` to simplify your input handling.
- You can use `str.format` to simplify all the `prints`.
- You don't handle incorrect data well. What if I enter 3 or 5 numbers?
- Your code doesn't run in \$O(n)\$ time, it runs in \$O(n^2)\$ time. I recommend that you ignore \$O\$ and just get working code if you're a novice. After you get it working make it readable. Finally here you should time your code to see if you need to then optimize it.
- Use functions, they make your code easier to use.

```
import json


def handle_input(input_):
    try:
        data = json.loads(input_)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid format.')

    if len(data) != 4:
        raise ValueError(f'Incorrect amount of numbers, got {len(data)} not 4.')
    return data


def main():
    print('Enter four numbers in brackets. E.g. [1, 2, 3, 4]')
    data = handle_input(input())
    print(
        '{0} {1} {2} {3}\n'
        '{3} {2} {1} {0}\n'
        '{1} {0} {3} {2}\n'
        '{2} {3} {0} {1}\n'
        .format(*data)
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, but should '{3} {2} {2} {0}\n' be '{3} {2} {1} {0}\n'?

Comment: @TravisWells You are correct, I have updated the answer to account for this.

Comment: Also for some strange reason. I get an error.  Try it and run it in the link below. You'll see. It seems to be fixed if you switch it 4 to a 5 (line 10). And again, I appreciate your answer.  That should work. https://repl.it/repls/SquareLinearConferences

Comment: @TravisWells I accidentally used `!=` rather than `==`. The program told you what the problem was tho, so it shouldn't be a 'strange reason'.

Comment: yeah, I'm still a novice. I have to keep learning syntax errors. Just trying to be observant.